# Host Service - [WCF] - IIS - [WCF] - Silverlight all asynchronously

Tags: silverlight, wcf, iis, asynchronous, callback

I'm looking for an explicit example if possible - linked or embedded here. I've searched and searched but only found samples alluding to what I'm attempting.

Desired sequence of communication:

1) Silverlight client connects through WCF web service running on IIS to request job run.

2) IIS web service connects through WCF to backend service to request job run.

3) IIS returns job REQUEST results to Silverlight client.

4) Backend service executes the long running asynchronous job.

5) Backend service generates job execution results.

6) Backend reconnects to IIS via WCF (CallbackContract?) to deliver results.

7) IIS reconnects to Silverlight to deliver results.

Firstly, I'm familiar with many of the duplex service contract examples. But these never deal with a truly disconnected back end service which itself runs asynchronously.

So, secondly, can this be accomplished at all?

Thirdly, if so, how?

At 6) is it even possible to reconnect to an IIS web service using a CallbackContract?

At 7) where does IIS get the client context now to send back the result?

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: I know this was long ago, but what was your solution?  I'm hooking up a Silverlight app and IIS server to a report-generator server, so my cast of characters matches yours.

Comment: • First off, Silverlight? I'm pretty sure it's dead. Websockets and SignalR are how you might want to approach this now. Connect, and stay connected until the job is complete.
• Alternatively, you could use a service that responds immediately (REST) with, "your report will be complete in about 20 seconds" (this as a response time, not an actual message). And then with the timer set, you poll back at the location the service said the report would be made available -- until it is.